# Why does my Inkscape export PDF look different from original SVG file?

Tags: inkscape, svg, pdf, export

Why is stroke in my exported PDF black while it's gray in *Inkscape*?

This is how it looks in *Inkscape*:

[image: sample with grey letters]

However, the exported PDF stroke become black inside:

[image: sample with black letters]

How can I fix this?

[Here](https://svgshare.com/i/j9J.svg) is my *Inkscape* file just incase that you want to check it.

**EDIT:** I think I found the explanation. Somehow I added stroke paint to a flat color and it causes the problem.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE I can't reproduce the problem using your file. The SVG and PDF look exactly the same as your first example image.  How are you viewing the PDF?  Try using Adobe Reader.

Comment: @BillyKerr I tried both Adobe Reader and Forxit reader and both show the problem. Also it's visible from the image above if you zoom in a bit? I also tried with Inkscape in both my PC and laptop and have the same problem.

Comment: I'm using a Windows PC (Win 10), Adobe Reader DC, and the latest Inskcape (1.2). Sorry, but I just can't reproduce the problem. Here is [what the PDF looks like zoomed in.](https://imgur.com/efZuLyk) - are you exporting the PDF directly from Inkscape?  Are you using File > Save As?

Comment: I think I found your problem. I've added an answer now!

Answer (score 7):

I think I've found the problem. At first I couldn't reproduce this, but I can if I use the Export panel for exporting the PDF.

The Export panel PDF export is really brand new functionality. Wouldn't surprise me if this is a bit buggy. If so, you should perhaps report it.

To fix it, do *File > Save As* instead. The issue is not present in a PDF exported in this way.

Here's the PDF viewed zoomed in, using "Save As" for the export method.

[image]

Comment: I think I found the explanation. Somehow I added stroke paint to a flat color and it causes the problem.

Comment: @hana - but that shouldn't really cause a problem.

Comment: I think it is as I deleted that and it also solved the problem.

Comment: @hana Yes, but adding a stroke to letters should not cause a problem when exporting a PDF. This sounds like a bug.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm not quite sure about that.